# Combining two CCSprites to make one CCSprite

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite, ccsprite, cclayer

Is it possible to have `CCSprite * sprite1` and `CCSprite * sprite 2` combined? For example if you took a piece of white paper (`sprite1)` and glued a red piece of paper with a cut out, reassembling transparent areas, (`sprite2`) on top of the white paper to create a new `CCSprite * sprite3`, so as to only have one child of the `CCLayer` it would be added too? Instead of simply adding `sprite2` as child of `sprite1` and then adding `sprite1` to the `CCLayer`. I am trying to keep children of the layer to a minimum for performance.

Comment: looks to me like you are worrying about being worried ! did you measure any 'performance' related issue ?

Comment: Yes on iPhone 5 I have 60 fps while on 3G it drops to 30

Comment: wait, you're still developing for 3G? Let that go....

Comment: also number of sprites isn't the problem when they are properly batch drawn

Comment: should I develop for iPhone 4?

Comment: The "sprites" I am working with are CCTMXLayers which are largely transparent. I feel it would be more efficient if I could somehow draw them as a single image rather than 50+ large, mostly transparent images.

Comment: I believe you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Problem or no problem, my question is if it is possible to layer two sprites to create one.